# Swift Optimise nested async calls

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore

I have this case where I need to make 3 nested async calls to receive the data I want.
So the second call needs data from the first one and the third one needs data from the second one. I do not have a lot of cases like this. Only this one and another one with only two nested call so I was thinking about a pure swift solution without any external libraries but I'm open to everything.

*Since I'm using Firebase, is it better to move this logic to CloudFunctions? So to prepare it in the backend?*

```
FirestoreService().fetchCollection(query: query) { (result: Result<[Request], Error>) in
    // do stuff
    FirestoreService().fetchCollection(query: query) { (result: Result<[Request], Error>) in
        // do stuff
            FirestoreService().fetchDocument(documentReference: documentReference) { (result: Result<Package, Error>) in
                // finish
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Actually after looking at your question, I don't think you need my solution... The answer is: yes, it's better to move this logic to backend

Comment: Is there any reason why this logic cannot move to backend? I would suggest call a single API which would do all these nested calls for you, for the sake of conversation even if you are somehow able to do a nested calls then what happens if out of 3 any one or two or all calls fail? You need to write a lot of plumbing code to just handle errors here

Answer (score 1):

If you don't to used 3rd party library, then probably you want to consider wrap those operations inside some class, and utilise closure in imperative way.

here is the sample:

```
class CustomFirestoreHandler {

    private var onFetchFirstQueryArrived: ((Result<[Request], Error>) -> ())? = nil
    private var onFetchSecondQueryArrived: ((Result<[Request], Error>) -> ())? = nil
    private var onFetchDocumentArrived: ((Result<Package, Error>) -> ())? = nil

    init() {

        onFetchFirstQueryArrived = { [weak self] (result: Result<[Request], Error>) in
            self?.executeSecondQuery()
        }

        onFetchSecondQueryArrived = { [weak self] (result: Result<[Request], Error>) in
            self?.executeFetchDocument()
        }
    }

    func executeQuery(completion: @escaping (Result<Package, Error>) -> ()) {

        self.onFetchDocumentArrived = completion

        FirestoreService().fetchCollection(query: query) { [weak self] (result: Result<[Request], Error>) in 

            // validate if some error occurred and do early return here, so that we don't need necessarily call second query.
            if (result.error == whatever) {
                 self?.onFetchDocumentArrived?(result)
                 return
            }

            self?.onFetchFirstQueryArrived?(result)
        }
    }

    private func executeSecondQuery() {
        FirestoreService().fetchCollection(query: query) { [weak self] (result: Result<[Request], Error>) in 

            // validate if some error occurred and do early return here, so that we don't need necessarily call fetch document.
            if (result.error == whatever) {
                 self?.onFetchDocumentArrived?(result)
                 return
            }

            self?.onFetchSecondQueryArrived?(result)
        }
    }

    private func executeFetchDocument() {
        FirestoreService().fetchDocument(documentReference: documentReference) { (result: Result<Package, Error>) in
            self?.onFetchDocumentArrived?(result)
        }
    }

}
```

And here's the usage of `CustomFirestoreHandler` above :

```
let firestoreHandler = CustomFirestoreHandler()
firestoreHandler.executeQuery { (result: Result<Package, Error>) in
    // Handle `result` here...
}
```

I know it look complicated, but this is the only way I think (CMIIW) at the moment to prevent pyramid of dooms since swift doesn't have async await style(just like javascript does).